# How to turn on tap visual feedback from the command line

Tags: adb

There is an option in debug mode that shows/hides tap visual feedback:
[image]

[This](https://youtu.be/yHhM1lqvV5w) is what happens when you turn that option on.

I like to quickly record videos from the command line and I like to toggle this option from the command line as well. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056918/how-to-enable-show-touches-developer-option-from-adb-shell

Comment: yes it's perfect!

Comment: You're welcome (: